# Background hidden when overlaying header with negative top margins

Tags: html, css, image, margin, background-color

I am trying to overlay a header onto an image. However the background is hidden under the image.
Why is this happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/YRDFB/

```
<div class="header">
<img width="100%" height="200px"  src="/path/to/image.jpg" />
<h1>Header Title</h1></div>


h1 {
    background: rgba(67,67,67,0.8);
    margin-top: -3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 2 solutions here:

1. Using `display:inline-block` and set `width:100%` for your `h1`, also use negative `margin-bottom` on the `img` instead:

   ```
   h1 {
     background: rgba(67,67,67,0.8);    
     display:inline-block;
     width:100%;
   }
   img {
     margin-bottom:-4em;
   }
   ```

   ### [Demo 1.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/YRDFB/3/)
2. Using `position:relative` for the img and set `z-index:-1` for it:

   ```
   h1 {
     background: rgba(67,67,67,0.8);    
   }
   img {
     margin-bottom:-4em;
     position:relative;
     z-index:-1; 
   }
   ```

   ### [Demo 2.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/YRDFB/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YRDFB/7/)**

```
h1 {
background: rgba(67, 67, 67, 0.8);
position:relative;
z-index:9;
display:block;
width:100%;
padding:0;
color:#fff;
margin-top:-43px;
}
```