# Negative margin remove background property of static siblings

Tags: html, css

I am using negative margin on bottom to pull the adjacent element to overlap current element. It is my intention to make it overlap. But I want the whole div to be overlapped above the image. But, it turned out that it removes the background of the pulled element as well. Can someone explained this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    .div1 {
      background-color: black;
    }

    img {
      margin-bottom:-20px;
    }
  
  </style>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="">
        <div class="div1">
          Here is example text
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/mejoci/edit?html,css,output

EDITED: It is kinda working when the element is positioned(fixed|relative|absolute) but not with static position which is the default position even when position is not set.

Comment: add img { max-width: 100%;}

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sewovojoko/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @LaljiTadhani: I am not just looking for solution on how to implement this kind of style, but I want to know the reason of this problem happening. But yeah, your approach looks like working. What makes the div1 overlap though?

Comment: img size is big to parent element

Comment: negative margin overlap the sibling element. Just use `position:relative` to sibling element will make `.div1` over to image.

Comment: @ketan: Overlapping sibling element supposedly will not remove the background right?

Comment: There are already same issue people get but don't know why only background-color ovelap not text. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285146/background-hidden-when-overlaying-header-with-negative-top-margins and http://htmlasks.com/overlay_a_img_tag_with_a_div_using_negative_margin_top_on_the_sibling_div

Comment: related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25055301/703717) question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sample code, both elements share the same stacking context.

That being the case, the rules which define how elements are layered are defined in [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) as follows: (bold is mine)

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. **the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.**
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. **the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.**
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

So you can see that - **within the same stacking context** - **inline-level elements** (#5) **are painted *above* non-inline-level elements** (#3)

So in your case - since both the `<img>` and the `<div>` share the same stacking context and the `<img>` element is an inline-level element - it is painted **above** the `<div>` - even though the `<div>` occurs later in the document tree order.

Check out this [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/rxzJOm?editors=110) which illustrates this point further

---

**Extra reading:**

[Elaborate description of Stacking Contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html)

[Stacking without z-index (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)

[Z-Index And The CSS Stack: Which Element Displays First?](http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/)

Comment: When I make the div as positioned for instance relative, it will fall under #6 then?

Comment: How about setting the image to be max-width: 100%? It seems like solving the issue but I am not sure it falls under what category

Answer (score -1):

Position: relative will solve your issue of overlapping

```
<style>
    .div1 {
      background-color: black;
      position: relative;
    }

    img {
      margin-bottom:-20px;
    }

  </style>
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Because your img : margin-bottom will overlap with -20px that you have defined that property , so to remove that overlap issue you should define position:relative on overlapped controll(that is div)

so relative means positioned relative to its normal position will show div clear and 

it will be exactly as it would be.