# CSS stack order changes when parent content has image as child, and also other element has opacity

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I found strange behavior when coding css specifically using negative margin to stack element on other element.

I understand natural stack order that when elements overlap, later element always goes on top(not using relative, absolute positioning).

Question1: Why If former element has image element, later element go under the image?

Question2: Moreover, when later element has opacity other than 1, later element go over the former element (set back to natural order?)

HTML:

```
<div class="box sample1">
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/100/100" alt="">
</div>
<div class="box sample1-2">opacity: 1</div>


<div class="box sample1-3">
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/100/100" alt="">
</div>
<div class="box sample1-4">opacity: .9</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.child {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
.sample1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 300px !important;
}
.sample1-2 {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: -40px;

    .child {
        // background-color: green;
    }
}

.sample1-3 {
    // opacity: .9;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: green;
}
.sample1-4 {
    opacity: .9; //this changes stack order
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/4w62t746/8/

Need a little explanation to this, thanks.

Comment: this question was already asked but am not able to find it :)  when you change opacity the flow is rebuilt again, and order is changed

Comment: @TemaniAfif - here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740422/negative-margin-remove-background-property-of-static-siblings/34778607#34778607 - that explains why the **former** image element is rendered above the later element... as for the opacity part of the question - it's because a new stacking context is formed on an element with a opacity value less than 1

Comment: @Danield yes this one is helpfull too, but i remember an older one with many answers :)

Comment: sorry guys i was not able to find similar question here, maybe because wrong keyword search, my bad.
I also googled and found an article element stack order clearly explains.
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/what-you-may-not-know-about-the-z-index-property--webdesign-16892
this might help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question1: Why If former element has image element, later element go
>   under the image?

It's because within the same stacking context - inline-level elements (such as the image) are painted above non-inline-level elements (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34778607/703717))

[This article](http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/) has a nice image to sum up the stacking order of elements within the same stacking context:

[image]

> Question2: Moreover, when later element has opacity other than 1,
>   later element go over the former element (set back to natural order?)

It's because a new stacking context is formed on an element with a opacity value less than 1.

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency): (bold mine)

> If an element with opacity less than 1 is positioned, the ‘z-index’
>   property applies as described in [CSS21], except that ‘auto’ is
>   treated as ‘0’ **since a new stacking context is always created**.

See all [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) on stacking contexts.

Comment: Bit tricky and interesting spec opacity level rather than 1 creates new stacking context.